# Tips for increasing power of bankai

Tags: kendo

So I was practicing with my bankai  today and I just feel like I could be generating much more force. Does anyone know of a couple of exercises I could do to increase my reiatsu?

Comment: Also note the date.

Comment: You need to meditate in a zero G environment until your power level is at least over 9000

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about stupid TV shows

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an April fools joke after April.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the Trials of the Shattered Shaft is what you are looking for.  However, there's some risks in attempting it.  Maybe you should talk to Urahara?

Comment: Also note the date.